# asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield, timeout=60000) doesn't wait for the task to finish

Tags: python, asynchronous, boto3, python-asyncio

I have the following code in Python to interact with S3 objects:

```
import boto3
import botocore.exceptions as bexc
import asyncio
import aioboto3
from aiobotocore.session import get_session
import gzip
import utils.processor as processor

async def download_s3_async(self, file):   
    session = aioboto3.Session(profile_name=self.current_profile)
            
    async with session.client("s3") as client:
        start_log = processor.cf_get_start_time_from_filename(file.split("/")[3])
        end_log = processor.cf_get_end_time_from_filename(file.split("/")[3])   

        s3_obj = await client.get_object(Bucket=self.cf_bucket, Key=file)
        task = s3_obj["Body"].read()

        try:
            cat = await asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(task), timeout=60000000)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print('Gave up waiting, task canceled')

        res = gzip.decompress(cat).decode("utf-8")

        print("File with {}-{} timestamp was downloaded and decompressed".format(start_log, end_log))
        return res

async def iterate(self, files):
    result = await asyncio.gather(*map(self.download_s3_async, files))
    return result

def call_async_wrapper(self, s_time, e_time):
    files = self.get_s3_objects_list(s_time, e_time)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    results = loop.run_until_complete(self.iterate(files))
    return results      

def get_waf_actors_info(self, s_date, s_time, e_time):
    self.current_dist = "somepath/path/{}/".format(str(s_date).replace("-", ""))
    self.call_async_wrapper(s_date, s_time, e_time)
```

Files are downloaded for some time, but then suddenly asyncio.TimeoutError is caught and the task gets cancelled. And it's less than a minute (tried 1000000 timeouts as well).

What am I doing wrong?

```
...
File with 00:01:29-00:01:59 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:00:24-00:00:54 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:03:33-00:04:03 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:07:01-00:07:31 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:01:01-00:01:31 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:06:14-00:06:44 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:03:59-00:04:29 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:03:02-00:03:32 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:09:06-00:09:36 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:04:12-00:04:42 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:02:32-00:03:02 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:02:23-00:02:53 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:00:08-00:00:38 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:09:31-00:10:01 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
File with 00:00:23-00:00:53 timestamp was downlaoded and decompressed
Gave up waiting, task canceled
```

Should not asyncio.shield prevent the task from timing out?

Comment: I solved the problem by adding the following lines (raising the timeout for reading):

```config = botocore.client.Config(connect_timeout=900, read_timeout=900)
        session = aioboto3.Session(profile_name=self.current_profile)
               
        async with session.client("s3", config=config) as client:```. However, it's still unclear to me why `asyncio.wait_for(asyncio.shield(task), timeout=1000)` would not work.

Comment: I can guess at the reason.  If task raises a TimeoutError internally, that will be propagated to the caller of wait_for.  Shielding the task from cancellation doesn't prevent it from raising other exceptions.  Just because you catch a TimeoutError doesn't mean that the wait_for timeout was the cause.  Perhaps you can look at the entire traceback or wrap the task in a try:except: block and convert the TimeoutError to some other Exception subclass to isolate the problem.